# How to make a limit on in the loop of a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to make a limit on the loop but I can't make one. I am trying to also have the echo on. Then the numbers that are supposed to be after the echo, are supposed to have limits. After i set the limits for the numbers, I am trying to stop the loop after 200 times. Anyone know?

```
@echo off

set /a dd=%random% * 9 / 32768 + 1

set /a aa=%random% * 9 / 32768 + 1

set /a gg=%random% * 9 / 32768 + 1

set /a jj=%random% * 9 / 32768 + 1

set /a mm=%random% * 9 / 32768 + 1

set limit=200

for /L %dd% in (1,1,200) DO goto ALIVE

for /L %aa% in (1,1,200) DO goto ALIVE

for /L %gg% in (1,1,200) DO goto ALIVE

for /L %jj% in (1,1,200) DO goto ALIVE

for /L %mm% in (1,1,200) DO goto ALIVE
:ALIVE

cls

ECHO %dd%%aa%%gg%%jj%%mm% /? /? /? /?

goto ALIVE
```

Comment: First: read again `for /?`. Second: any `goto` breakes the `for`loop. Third: re-think about the logical program flow, there is an endless loop.

Comment: The batch file you are using is very floored. What do you want the batch file to do.

Answer (score 0):

I am just guessing. The Batch file below show 200 lines, each one with a number comprised of 5 random digits between 1 and 9:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

cls
set limit=200
for /L %%i in (1,1,%limit%) do (
   set /a dd=!random! * 9 / 32768 + 1
   set /a aa=!random! * 9 / 32768 + 1
   set /a gg=!random! * 9 / 32768 + 1
   set /a jj=!random! * 9 / 32768 + 1
   set /a mm=!random! * 9 / 32768 + 1
   ECHO !dd!!aa!!gg!!jj!!mm! /? /? /? /?
)
```